# How to check if a sequence of number is time series or not?

Tags: r, time-series

I have following numbers

```
0.889046409368551 1.22726162946495 1.22726162946495 1.35785109728356 
 1.35785109728356 1.10704609982913 1.4424189950435 1.2277843378837 
 1.35785109728356 0.970883941918588 0.822170913920467 1.35785109728356 
 0.358815782262543 0.774234247460432 0.822170913920467 0.822170913920467 
 0.72599976881814 0.671583894425946 0.813223271443211 0.774234247460432 
 1.00184802593319 1.4424189950435 1.22726162946495 0.970883941918588 
 0.358815782262543 1.31016840948316 0.970883941918588 1.4424189950435 
 0.889046409368551 4.91679981837699 1.2277843378837 1.21605333196293 
 0.369861996166875 0.774748148811057 0.369861996166875 1.4424189950435 
 1.22726162946495 1.4424189950435 1.22726162946495 1.16291100715022 
 2.33863311242767 0.774234247460432 4.91679981837699 0.9670580678417 
 0.970883941918588 0.9670580678417 1.10704609982913 4.91679981837699 
 1.4424189950435 1.05410985855726 1.22726162946495 1.21605333196293 
 1.35785109728356 0.822170913920467 1.4424189950435 0.970883941918588 
 0.835429195630044 0.774234247460432 1.61328986496929 0.970883941918588 
 1.2277843378837 1.22726162946495 0.970883941918588 1.10704609982913 
 1.10704609982913 1.10704609982913 1.4424189950435 1.22726162946495 
 1.4424189950435 1.35785109728356 0.9670580678417 0.9670580678417 
 0.885419165744907 1.16291100715022 0.369861996166875 0.9670580678417 
 0.774748148811057 1.22726162946495 1.4424189950435 1.22726162946495 
 1.31016840948316 0.813223271443211 1.4424189950435 0.822170913920467 
 1.05410985855726 0.853014111520372 1.3245534157835 0.774234247460432 
 0.774234247460432 1.22726162946495 0.889046409368551 1.4424189950435 
 0.842622628771215 0.889046409368551 0.889046409368551 1.31898472833595 
 1.4424189950435 1.35785109728356 0.682617341489085 0.965180291004232
```

I don't want to check by plotting the above data (because I have thousands of such data structures).

Is there any function in R to check it?

How can I check validity by programming?

Comment: It is a time series if the data are collected over time.

Comment: Assuming that the time series samples a continuous variable over time, there should be a way to measure the continuity of a sequence of numbers. That could be a good indicator of whether the data might come from a time series.

Comment: Sagar, what @Rob Hyndman's comment points out is that this question needs clarification in order to remain open, because at present it is without content.  While you're thinking about this, please review the answers to the other questions you have asked and kindly upvote the good ones and mark the best ones as accepted: this will help future visitors who have questions similar to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rob said if it is a sequence collected at time intervals it is by one definition a time series. It is another question as whether or not there is an temporal structure within the sequence. One could consider a sequence of numbers that are independently distributed as being generated from a mean model (0,0,0)(0,0,0) with perhaps some pulses or unusual values. In this light a sequence of numbers that is measured with a fixed frequency e.g. 1 every minute/hour/day/month  could be referred to as a cross-sectional series if there is no evidented structure between successive values such as an ARIMA structure or a deterministic based structure such as level shifts, seasonal-pulses and/or local time trends even though it was collected at specific intervals of time. All of this having been said , if a series can be classified as having no temporal dependency then one might refer to it as being equivalent to a non-time series and treat it accordingly.
I suggest that the OP program or acquire such functionality software that delivers parsimonious automatic ARIMA and the detection of seasonal pulses, level shifts, local time trends and various combinations of these two structures. If he finds that there is no proof of any of these structures being evident then he might classify it as a "non-time series"  or as Michael opined "white noise" or informationless using time structures.

Comment: I only differ with IrishStat with semantics.  If a series over time has no time structure people sometimes refer to it as white noise.  But it is still deifned to be a time series even though it is useless at predicting future values in the sequence.

Comment: how to find temporal dependency in time series? 
what is this OP program? 
`  x
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  2
6  2
7  2
8  2
9  2
10 2
11 2
12 2
`
is this is time series ?
in "forecast" package,there is auto.arima(() function,how can i used it for validity of data,as time series or not ?

Comment: Is the question really "is this data autocorrelated" or "is it stationary" or "is it trended" or something similar. It's hard for me to quite understand how you have a pile of data that (a) you don't know enough about the data to know if it is a time series and (b) the data are likely to provide useful information.  I'm thinking this is an answerable question, if the question was clearer.